# split result set into 10 groups

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have 91 returned result set from query. I want to split these 91 data into 10 groups equally. For example, 1~9 in group 1
10~18 in group 2
19~27 in group 3
28~36 in group 4
37~45 in group 5
46~54 in group 6
55~63 in group 7
64~72 in group 8
73~81 in group 9
82~90 in group 10
I used row_num to see the order in number for the result set. but I have no idea how to split these data into 10 groups equally. please help me to figure it out! thank you.

```
set @row_num=0;
    select t.*
    from
        (
        select
                (@row_num:=@row_num+1) AS row_num,
                total.reg_date,
                total.car_id,
                total.mcu_motspd
        from(
            select
                td.reg_date,
                td.car_id,
                td.mcu_motspd
            from
                cartracker.tracker_data td
            left join car c on (c.car_device_no = td.car_id)
            left join car_group cg on (c.car_group_no = cg.car_group_no)
            where cg.car_group_no = "1"
            group by DATE_FORMAT(td.reg_date, "%Y%M%d%h%m")
            )total
        group by DATE_FORMAT(total.reg_date, "%Y%M%d%h%m")
        ) t
```

In conclusion, I want to split 91 result set from above query into 10 groups as group1, group2....etc.(I tried ntile function in mysql, but it did not work)
[ResultSet Image from the above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYzZS.png)

Comment: How about making a sample data [in a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7) and [post it in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64583778/edit). Judging from your query, you're not using MySQL version 8+ or MariaDB 10.2+, is that correct?

Comment: I am new to fiddle, but I will try ! I just checked the version and its 5.5.57-MariaDB

Comment: Its ok, you'll get use to it. In the meantime, are you able to upgrade your current database to at least MariaDB 10.2 version or above? Because I have an idea to make it work for you but the db needs to be able to use `ROW_NUMBER()` function instead of defining the row numbers using variables. What I mean is, its much more easier to achieve using that function.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade it because I am working on it with other people..

Comment: You don't have an `ORDER BY` clause in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's an idea. How about you divide the row_num result with 9 and do a `CEIL`(aka CEILING) function over it. Perhaps, something like this:

```
set @row_num=0;
    select CEIL(row_num/9), t.*
    from
        (
        select
                (@row_num:=@row_num+1) AS row_num,
                total.reg_date,
                total.car_id,
                total.mcu_motspd
        from(
            select
                td.reg_date,
                td.car_id,
                td.mcu_motspd
            from
                cartracker.tracker_data td
            left join car c on (c.car_device_no = td.car_id)
            left join car_group cg on (c.car_group_no = cg.car_group_no)
            where cg.car_group_no = "1"
            group by DATE_FORMAT(td.reg_date, "%Y%M%d%h%m")
            )total
        group by DATE_FORMAT(total.reg_date, "%Y%M%d%h%m")
    /*added order by*/
       ORDER BY total.reg_date, total.car_id,
        ) t
```

The `CEIL(row_num/9)` should give you result of 1-9 as 1, 10-18 as 2, 19-27 as 3 .. and so on. You don't have a sample data provided so I made a simple example of how the result will appear here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=19d23c0d22f6eb804ac458bc3a274d25

I was also thinking of maybe you were looking to pivot the results and summing all values that falls under the grouping of 1-9, 10-18 .. but that's only an assumption. However, if you are looking to do something like that, please update your question accordingly.